# Select distinct on two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'd like to select datas on tables without duplicates

For exemple

```
table1
data1; data2; data3; data4; data5

table2
data1; data2; data3
```

data1, data2, data3 are the same data type

table1

```
| data1    | data2    | data3    | data4    | data5    |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| value1.1 | value2.1 | value3.1 | value4.1 | value5.1 |
```

table2

```
| data1    | data2    | data3    |
|----------|----------|----------|
| value1.1 | value2.1 | value3.1 |
| value1.2 | value2.2 | value3.2 |
| value1.3 | value2.3 | value3.3 |
```

I'd like to select data1, data2, data3 from my two tables with a distinct data1

```
| data1    | data2    | data3    |
|----------|----------|----------|
| value1.1 | value2.1 | value3.1 |
| value1.2 | value2.2 | value3.2 |
| value1.3 | value2.3 | value3.3 |
```

I'd like to have my result in only 3 columns
for exemple value1.1 is from table1 and value1.2 is from table2

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This is very confused. Could you please show the content of table1 and table2 and not just the expected result?

Comment: Use `UNION` to get the required result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, you want the following:

```
SELECT  data1, data2, data3
FROM    table1
UNION /* Union without optional ALL will eliminate duplicates accross the two tables */
SELECT  data1, data2, data3
FROM    table2
```

However, there is still something you need to clarify. You state:

> I'd like to select data1, data2, data3 from my two tables with a distinct data1

The problem is that you don't say what should happen if you have a duplicate `data1` accross the two tables.

Suppose `table1` has a row with values `(1, A, B)` and `table2` has a row with values `(1, X, Y)`.  Which row should be included in the final output?
The above query will include both rows because they differ in columns: `data2` and `data3`.

---

**EDIT for comment**:

> if duplicate I'd like to have the table1 result

You still need `UNION`, but you need to control which rows are to be included in the union. NOTE: Because your query will now ensure there are no duplicates, you can use `UNION ALL` so the DMBS doens't waste processing time trying to eliminate duplicates that don't exist.

```
SELECT  data1, data2, data3
FROM    table1
UNION ALL
SELECT  data1, data2, data3
FROM    table2
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.data1 = table2.data1)
```

Comment: if duplicate I'd like to have the table1 result

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. The UNION will get you DISTINCT result:

```
SELECT data1, data2, data3 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT data1, data2, data3 FROM table2;
```